# Minimal logging not happening for INSERT INTO temp table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have an SP with a set of 3 temp tables created within the SP with no indexes. All three are inserted into using INSERT INTO ... WITH (TABLOCK). The database recovery model is SIMPLE for userDB as well as tempDB.

This SP is generating and inserting new data and a Transaction Commit/Rollback is good enough to maintain data integrity. So I want it to do minimal logging which I think I have enabled by using the TABLOCK hint.

I am checking the log generation before and after execution of the SP using below query and see no difference in log generation after adding the TABLOCK hint. (Checking in tempDB as tables are temp tables)

```
SELECT count(1) as NumLogEntries
            , sum("log record length") as TotalLengthWritten
FROM fn_dblog(null, null);
```

Is there anything else I need to do in order to enable minimal logging?

PN: I am able to see reduced logging if I use this hint to do the same INSERT INTO separately in management studio, but not if I do the same within the SP.
I have also tried adding the trace flag 610 ON before the insert statement but to no effect.